# AIMP remote control problem. Can not connect to local IP

Tags: networking, android, remote

I use an AIMP music player version 3.0 via Wine. This player has a remote control ability, so that you can control the player working on your laptop with your android phone. How it works is it has a plugin which listens to the port 3333 and recieves commands via this port. For plugin to work the phone application must connect to the ip address of the laptop with a specified port.

The problem is, despite being in one local network, the phone can not connect to laptop with it's ip address. I tried to look up the local ip address of the laptop in network connections it gives me 192.168.1.2. But i can not connect the phone application using this address.

Moreover, i tried to use "ping localhost" to get the right ip address. It gives me 127.0.0.1. And this address works if i open the browser on my laptop and type 127.0.0.1:3333 in the adress bar. The remote control page appears and i can control the player. However this does not work when i do the same in my phone's browser or the remote control application.

i use Lubuntu linux  14.04.3 LTS

what am i doing wrong when trying to connect the phone to a computer?